# The `input()` function gives me a NameError

Tags: python, string, input, printing

In this tutorial I'm following this program that asks the user for their name, and then responds with `hi" + name`. I followed the instructions but it isn't accepting inputs. Is the tutorial wrong/outdated?

```
print ("Hi! I’m Joseph. What's your name?")
name = input()
print ("Hi" + name)
```

It’s supposed to respond with a literal `Hi` and then the `name` but instead I am shown this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/AA school/ICT/python/Using str variables.py", line 2, in <module>
    name = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Adam' is not defined
```

I've tried changing the `+ name` to `+ str(name)`, and putting spaces in and removing them from different areas of the code.

What’s wrong?

Comment: You are the one with the outdated Python version. ;) Switch to Python3 or use `raw_input`.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: You should put the prompt as an argument to `input()` or `raw_input()` rather than printing it separately.

Comment: @DanFarrell Why do you think that? It's the expected error with Python 2.x.

Comment: lol, because I'm dumb :P . always forget `input()` is an eval-like operation in 2.x

Comment: change the second line to `name = raw_input()` and add a space in the third line right after hi (so `"hi "`). `input()` is what you use in python 3.x. The equivalent in python 2.7 is `raw_input()`.